# Is there a way to configure Debezium to store in Kafka not all the changes from database but only a certain ones?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, debezium

I have mongodb and I need to send the changes from a certain query to kafka broker. I heard that debezium tracks changes from database and stores it to kafka. But is there a way to configure that process to store not all the changes that happen in database but only a certain ones?

Comment: You mean skip some tables or skip some rows/changes in a table?

Comment: @GerardGarcia For example track only insert changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform some filtering using their single message transform (SMT) Kafka Connect plugin. You can check its documentation to see if it has the features that you need: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/filtering.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the source technology you could.

When using PostgreSQL as a source, for example, you can define which operations to include in the PG publication that is read by Debezium

More info at the [Debezium docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpublication.html)